# Batch PDF editor

Tags: pdf, pdf-editor

A friend has 100 different PDF files. He wants to replace some text, the text is the same in all files. The software should be able to edit all of files at once.

Ideally the software should be able to scan a directory full of PDFs, manipulate them, then save them.

My friend uses Ubuntu and Windows, so either OS is fine. Ideally he's looking for a freeware.

Comment: Whoa, I just came to SR looking for software for exactly this type of job, and saw your question randomly on the front page.

Comment: @Fiksdal Telepathy :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [changepagestring.pl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CAM-PDF/bin/changepagestring.pl) (based on [CAM-PDF](http://search.cpan.org/dist/CAM-PDF/)):

- Open source
- Gratis
- Cross-platform
- Search a string or a regular expression, and replace in all PDF pages

Comment: in all pdf pages? not files? can it scan multiple files?

Comment: Since it's CLI you can call it for each file in a directory.

Comment: Please note that if the pdf files are from a scanner or the like they contain images rather than text so this, _and most other_, solutions will __not__ work on such files.

Comment: @SteveBarnes in that case you can use Adobe Acrobat for OCR (it can batch process).